# Does this system of linear equations have infinite solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$x(k+2)+y(k−1)+z(k)=2$$
$$y(k+2)+2z=0$$
$$z(k^2+k−2)=k+2$$

Is there any value of k for which this system of linear equations would have infinite solutions? I mean, it seems as if it does when k = -2, but it also seems as if it has no solutions when k = -2. I'm looking at this from a row-echelon form augmented matrix point of view and I really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k=-2$, the system has rank $2$:
$$\begin{cases}-3y-2z=2\\2z=0\end{cases}$$
hence the solutions are $\{(x,-\frac23,0)\mid x\in\mathbf R\}$. It does have an infinite set of solutions, the straight line $\;(0,-\frac23,0)+x(1,0,0)$.

If $k=1$, the system also has rank $2$:
$$\begin{cases}3x+z=2\\3y+2z=0\\0=3\end{cases}$$
but the last line is not identically $0$, hence there is no solution.

On all other cases, the ystem has rank $3$ and has a unique solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The z part in the 2nd equation is actually $2z$ rather than $2z(k)$ . Sorry for the mistake, does this still apply?

Comment: Yes, but I'll correct the details.

Comment: Thanks again. One last thing, I don't really understand the notation you used for the infinite set of solutions. If you don't mind, could you please write it in terms of an equation(s).

Comment: Do you know about parametric equations of line in $3$-space? As to the first way of writing, (as a *set* of solutions) I think it is standard. I really don't see how to write it differently. It just means: choose $x$ as you please, and $y=-\frac23,\ z=0$. Is that clearer with these details?

Comment: For example for the system of equations: $2x + y = 5$, $2x + z = 3$, $0x + 0y + 0z = 0$,  the full set of solutions can be described with $ y = 5 - 2x$ and $z = 3 - 2x$

Comment: That's what I wrote. What seems to disturb you is that  neither $y$ nor $z$ depend on $x$ here: $x=$, well… $x$, $y=-\frac23$, $z=0$. Graphically, it's a line parallel to the $x$-axis in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: ohhh, that makes sense. Thanks for everything :)

Comment: You're welcome. I really think it's the unusual set of solutions that caused you problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

hope you will understand this.